# Enzyme not selecting an onClick for a component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a Component `Header` component which takes an `action` prop which takes `text` and `onClick` event handler. An example component:

```
<Header id="someId" action={{ text: 'Text', onClick: () => onClickHandler() }}/>
```

The way I've tested it is :

```
wrapper
      .find('#someId')
      .first()
      .prop('action')
      .simulate('click')
```

I get an error : `wrapper.find(...).first(...).prop(...).simulate is not a function, where could I be going wrong?`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: I had to call `onClick()` on prop `action`

```
    wrapper
          .find('#ihm-unified-move-tool-verify-and-process-item')
          .first()
          .prop('action')
          .onClick() // change
```